# Show that $u$ is the real part of $g$ and $g(0) = 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, harmonic-functions

Let $u:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a harmonic function and $u(0)=0$. Let $$
g(z)= 2 \int_{0}^z \frac{\partial u}{\partial z}(\xi)\,d\xi,$$
suppose we know that $g$ is analytic, show that $u$ is the real part of $g$
and $g(0) = 0$.

My approach:

I couldn't use the fact that $u$ is harmonic. Can someone give me some idea?

Comment: Actually, from Newton's theorem,
$$
 g(z) = 2(u(z) - u(0)) = 2u(z)
$$
Thus
$$
 g(0) = 2u(0) = 0.
$$

Comment: What is newtons theorem?

Comment: How did you get $g(z) = 2z \partial u / \partial z$? In any case, the "Newton's theorem" alluded to by @mattecapu (which is basically just fundamental theorem of calculus) would only apply if the function $u$ is complex differentiable, which is not the case here.

Comment: I just use the definition of the line integral. And when I check now, it may be incorrect.

Comment: Can you give me some more hints on this? I am really confused.

Comment: Is this a course in harmonic function theory, or a course in complex analysis? The assumption that $g$ is analytic is superfluous, since you can prove it by differentiating under the integral sign. Do you know how to prove that $g(z) = 2 \int_0^z \frac{\partial \Re(g)}{\partial z} ~\mathrm{d}\xi$ for $g$ holomorphic?

Comment: One also needs that the integral be well defined - i.e., the path is not specified. On the other hand, as $u$ is harmonic, $$ {\partial \over \partial \overline z }{\partial \over \partial z } u = 0,$$ so  if $\gamma$ is a nice closed path enclosing a region $R$,
$$ \int_\gamma {\partial \over \partial z } u\, dz = \int_R  {\partial \over \partial \overline z }{\partial \over \partial z } u\, d\overline z \,d z = 0,$$
so the integral of the question is path independent and well defined.  All agree?